# How to solve this equation with another way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the  equation
$$\left(\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{x+1}{x-3}\right) = 12\left(\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}\right)^2$$
I want to solve this equation in the set of all real numbers.

First way. Put $t = \dfrac{x-2}{x-3}$, and then $x = \dfrac{3t-2}{t - 1}$
Substitute $t$ onto  the given equation, we have
\begin{equation*}
12t^4-4t^3-13t^2+24t-9 = 0.
\end{equation*}
This equation has two roots $t = -\dfrac{3}{2}$ and $t=\dfrac{1}{2}$.
And then, the given equation has roots $x= \dfrac{13}{5}$ and $x=1$.

Please solve for me the given equation with another way. Thank you very much.

I have just found another way.  The given equation equavalent to 
\begin{equation*}
\left(\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{x+1}{x-2} \right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{x-2}{x-3} \right) = 12\left(\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}\right)^2.
\end{equation*}
Put $a = \dfrac{x+1}{x-2}$ and $b = \dfrac{x-2}{x-3}$, we get
\begin{equation*}
a^2 + ab - 12b^2 = 0.
\end{equation*}
Solve this equation, we get $a = -4b$ and $a = 3b$.

With $a = -4b$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{x+1}{x-2} = -4 \dfrac{x-2}{x-3}.
\end{equation*}
This equation has two roots $x= \dfrac{13}{5}$ and $x=1$.

With $a = 3b$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{x+1}{x-2} =3 \dfrac{x-2}{x-3}.
\end{equation*}
has no real solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't just multiply through by denominators to end up with a quartic in $x$? I'm not sure why you made a substitution.

Comment: Thank you. Solve your way, we get
$$\dfrac{10x^4-86x^3+281x^2-400x+195}{(x-2)^2 \cdot (x-3)^2}=0.$$

Comment: I like the new way, the one which introduces the extra factor in the 2nd term.

Comment: You can close a question when you feel you've already found your answer.